# Spark fails at `bytesInJava = self._jrdd.collect().iterator()`

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm suffering a problem while using spark on some task.

If I just run `spark-submit test.py` locally, then the python works perfect.
However, when I do `spark-submit --master yarn-client test.py`.

the test.py looks like:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext,rdd
sc = SparkContext(appName='behaviour')

def train_rdd_op_log(type = 0,dir = '/user/xxxxx'):
    rdd_data = sc.textFile(dir)
    rdd_data = rdd_data.map(lambda x : training_format_text_log(x))
    return rdd_data

def training_format_text_log(text_log):
    text_log = text_log.split('\x01')
    return text_log

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = train_rdd_op_log()
    result =result.collect()
    print result[0:10]
```

the file read from dir at each line would look like:

u'aaa\x01bbb\x01ccc'

I just want to seperate the string by '\x01'

The work fails at `collect()` part. The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/mnt/work/preprocessing/test.py", line 146, in <module>
    result = result.collect()
    File "/mnt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.8-1.cdh5.3.8.p0.5/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 676, in collect
    bytesInJava = self._jrdd.collect().iterator()
    File "/mnt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.8-1.cdh5.3.8.p0.5/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
    File "/mnt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.8-1.cdh5.3.8.p0.5/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o29.collect.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, stats-hadoop23): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: How can we help if we haven't seen your code? How about [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thanks, zero323. I though it's a general issue in python spark. Now, I attached the most concise code with the same error returned. Hoping it will help. Please let me know where I post the questions improperly, so that I can make some further update.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. The problem was at the spark-submit, it should be called like: spark-submit xx.py --master yarn-client

the xx.py file should be directly followed by spark-submit